# Simplifying a jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering the method of simplifying this script, because somehow I am repeating myself all over again...

```
$('.userprofile').click(function(){
    card_profile.load(url_settings).dialog('open');
});
$('.cust-profile').click(function(){
    card_profile.load(url_customer).dialog('open');
});
$('.my-profile').click(function(){
    card_profile.load(url_my).dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: Make an object with key/value pairs mapping the class name to the `url_` values, then enumerate the object, using the key for the selector, and the value for the `.load()` argument. This assumes the urls don't change. If they do, you'll need to update them in the object.

Comment: ...another option is to bind the same handler to all the classes, then use `.hasClass()` to choose which `url_` to use.

Comment: use `.hasClass()`? Can you show me an example? Sorry to trouble you, but I'm a bit new in this field...

Comment: Sure, I posted an answer with both examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var obj = {
    '.userprofile' : url_settings,
    '.cust-profile': url_customer,
    '.my-profile'  : url_my
};

$.each(obj, function(sel, url) {
    $(sel).click(function(){
        card_profile.load(url).dialog('open');
    });
});
```

---

or

```
$(".userprofile,.cust-profile,.my-profile").click(function() {
    var url = $(this).hasClass("userprofile")  ? url_settings :
              $(this).hasClass("cust-profile") ? url_customer :
                                                 url_my;
    card_profile.load(url).dialog("open");
});
```

Comment: I prefer the first one. Anyway, great respond from everyone. Thank you for taking your time! Great to have you guys around here.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to iterate over an array (or two) of strings.

Edit: declared `i` outside of for loop to address comment from @crazytrain

```
arr = ['user', 'cust', 'my'];
url_arr = [urlA, urlB, urlC];
var i;
for (i in arr){
    $('.' + arr[i] + '-profile').click(function(){
        card_profile.load(url_arr[i]).dialog('open');
    });
}
```

Comment: This won't work because the loop value of `i` won't be retained in the handler. *(JavaScript doesn't have block scope.)*

Comment: If you declare `i` outside of the loop (`var i;`), it should work fine, no?

Comment: No, the loop updates `i` with each iteration, but the current value in the loop isn't captured in the `click` handler. The handler creates a closure over the enclosing variable scope, which means it's going to *read* the current value of `i` when the click takes place. That value will be wherever it was left after the loop finished.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat better, but you can't get significant gain I guess:

```
$('.userprofile').data('url',url_settings);
$('.cust-profile').data('url',url_customer);
$('.my-profile').data('url',url_my);
$('.userprofile, .cust-profile, .my-profile').click(function(){
    card_profile.load($(this).data('url')).dialog('open');
});
```

If you assign URL to every button, then you don't have to repeat the classes:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    card_profile.load($(this).data('url')).dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: I like this solution the best. If possible, attach all the information needed as data attributes when serving the page, then use a generalized function to perform a given function using the element's data attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.my-profile, .userprofile, .cust-profile').click(function(){
    card_profile.load(url).dialog('open');
});
```

Edit: on second thoughts - do what Eltier says.

Comment: You're using the same `url` for all the elements.

Comment: Do what @eltiar says. I was just simplifying the selectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', function(e){
  if($(e.target).hasClass('userprofile')){
    card_profile.load(url_settings).dialog('open');
  }
  if($(e.target).hasClass('cust-profile')){
    card_profile.load(url_costumer).dialog('open');
  }
  if($(e.target).hasClass('myprofile')){
    card_profile.load(url_my).dialog('open');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little better with a function:

```
$('.userprofile').click(function(){
    loadDiag(url_settings);
});
$('.cust-profile').click(function(){
    loadDiag(url_customer);
});
$('.my-profile').click(function(){
    loadDiag(url_my);
});

function loadDiag(url){
    card_profile.load(url).dialog('open');
}
```

You could also `switch` through the parameter and do multiple things per click

Answer (score 0):

Assign a url attribute to each element. Then  you can retrieve that value and use in your code in this way.

```
$('.userprofile').attr('url',url_settings);
$('.cust-profile').attr('url',url_customer);
$('.my-profile').attr('url',url_my);
$('.my-profile, .userprofile, .cust-profile').click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('url');
    card_profile.load(url).dialog('open');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the html data attribute and have it simple like this

```
$('.userprofile, .cust-profile, .my-profile').click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
    card_profile.load( url ).dialog('open');
});

<div class="userprofile" data-url="settings.php">Settings</div>
```

And to make it even better you could add a class to all load items like this

```
$('.load-box').click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
    card_profile.load( url ).dialog('open');
});

<div class="userprofile load-box" data-url="settings.php">Settings</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save a parameter in de caller object and then do something like this:

```
$('.userprofile, .cust-profile, .my-profile').on('click',function(){
    var parameter = $(this).data( 'parameter' );
    card_profile.load( parameter ).dialog( 'open' );
});
```

You can find more information about storing data [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/), is very easy.

Comment: Where is `parameter` coming from?

Comment: As i say, you can save a parameter in de caller object using .data(), you can use url if is an anchor, or you can put de parameter in de html like this: <div class=".cust-profile" data-parameter="cust-profile"></div>.

Comment: It's just confusing. You're passing the value of the `parameter` variable, which will be `undefined`. Maybe you meant `.data("parameter")`

Answer (score 0):

Throwing another hat in the ring here...

```
var links = [{profile: '.userprofile', url: url_settings, clickDialog: 'open'},
             {profile: '.cust-profile', url: url_customer, clickDialog: 'open'},
             {profile: '.my-profile', url: url_my, clickDialog: 'open'}];

function clickOpen(url,value) {
    card_profile.load(url).dialog(value);
}

links.forEach(function(element) { $(element.profile).click(
clickOpen(element.url,element.clickDialog) });
```